# Saving list data composed of individual buttons

Tags: android, saving-data

I've made a list made of TextViews and Buttons, made that when a person clicks on a button, a fragment opens and there is a list of values he can select. The problem is when i press on another button to select a value again for a different field, the previous value disappears. So the question would be how to save the fragments values, and keep it saved until the app is closed ?

```
    priceButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    PriceFragment priceFragment = new PriceFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, priceFragment).commit();
    setToHideElements();
  }
});

yearButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    YearFragment yearFragment = new YearFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, yearFragment).commit();
    setToHideElements();

  }
});
```

this is the year fragment

```
    yearEndListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(), MainMenuActivity.class);
    String yearTo = yearList[i].toString();
    int yearTint = Integer.valueOf(yearTo);

    if (combinedYear != null) {
      combinedYear = combinedYear + " " + yearTo;
      intent.putExtra("Years", combinedYear);
      getActivity().startActivity(intent);

    } else {
      combinedYear = null;
      combinedYear = yearTo;
    }


    }
});
```

this is the method to retrive data

```
  private void retriveDataFromFragment(){
Intent intent = getIntent();
String fragmentDataPrice = intent.getStringExtra("PriceData");
String fragmentDataYear = intent.getStringExtra("Years");

if(fragmentDataPrice != null){
  priceButton.setText(fragmentDataPrice);
} else {}
if (fragmentDataYear != null){
  yearButton.setText(fragmentDataYear);
} else {}


}
```

I use `RetriveDataFromFragment` method in `OnResume` method.

Thank you, for your time.

Comment: You might want to add code so people know what you're doing and so they *could* possibly know what they have to change in order to make your code into something that works as you intended (namely that previous values wouldn't be lost) ;)

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to do so.. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the anwser if someone else needs a similar menu, all you have to do is create a class that extends `Application`, and include into your manifest (the part with application tags). From there you just use getters and setters and all is well.

Answer (score 0):

you are initiating every time a new fragment so it will never retain its state. you have to use listener while closing the fragment so you can get back your data.

Comment: I think you misunderstood since i didin't provide the code. i get the data from the fragments via listiner, but as soon as i open another fragment the data that was set to the previous button disappears